# modify controls of imagebutton through variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a group of imagebuttons in on a web application in c# where I want to change the visible state to true if a certain condition is met.  i.e. if I get ABC from the database I want to make visible the imagebutton c_ibABC.

Can anyone advise how I can change the control of an imagebutton through the variable name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `FindControl` method, this allows dynamically getting controls from the page.

```
protected ImageButton FindImageButton(string id)
{
    string fullId = "c_ib" + id;
    return Page.FindControl(fullId) as ImageButton;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Destrictor for the help, FindControl definitely looks as though it is the right way I should be doing this but I am still struggling to implement this so it works.

This is what I have tries

'ImageButton imagebutton = FindImageButton(sFullID);
imagebutton.Visible = true;'

and variations on this but imagebutton is always set as null getting Object ref not set error

Comment: @user2192142 Perhaps there's no object with that id on the page? If you're adding controls programmatically, are you making sure you're adding them _every_ postback?

Comment: Hi Yes they are added on postback.  On doing more research I have found that having a masterpage causes additional complications to this.  I have a masterpage and on viewing the source of the page my imagebutton control shows name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$c_ibABC" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_c_ibABC".  Any suggestions on how to programmatically set this control to visible = true in this instance?

Comment: @user2192142 Actually FindControl should work with those. ASP.Net automatically add those to make sure ids are unique. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx).

Comment: I have found a solution to the problem.  My page uses a masterpage and has a ContentPlaceHolder.  I looked in the source and the name of my control started with ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$.
Code used:

    '        protected ImageButton FindImageButton(string id)
        {
            string fullId = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$c_ib" + id;

            return Page.FindControl(fullId) as ImageButton;
        }'


I used this like this:
'                ImageButton tmpImageButton = FindImageButton(sFullID);
                tmpImageButton.Visible = true;'

Comment: What I am unsure of is if the ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ is static or if this will change or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @user2192142 ctl00 indicates the (absent of the) masterpage id. ContentPlaceHolder1 is the id of the contentplaceholder. The first part of the ClientID should be the same unless you start adding controls that implement INamingContainer (eg. ContentPlaceHolder and others see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Visible property to true.

```
buttonName.Visible=true;
```